# Typescript call function TypeError: this.array[i].greet is not a function

Tags: typescript

I'm getting an error when I try to call my function. If I create just one object of someClass and then call the greet function it works fine.

Not Working (some array is an array of type someClass):

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.someArray.length; i++) {

        this.someArray[i].greet();
}
```

Works:

```
let oneInstance: someClass = new someClass;
oneInstance.id = 'abc';
console.log(oneInstance.greet());
```

SomeArray is an array of my class someClass:

```
export class someClass implements ISomeClass {

    id: string;

    public greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare and populate `someArray`?

Comment: someArray: someClass[];
 
saved too quick. Then I call an HTTP service, populate the data into someArray. and then call a function that iterates through the list. if I do for instances console.log(this.someArray[i].id) I get a value if that helps.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you populate the data from the service?

Comment: this.someService.getSomeClass()
            .then(data => {
                this.someArray = data;
});

service looks like this:

    getSomeClass(): Promise<someArray[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.uri)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json().data as someArray[])
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that when you populate your array with data you're not creating instances of your class but assigning objects which share the same shape.

For example you're doing:

```
this.someArray = json.results;
```

Where `json.results` is:

```
[{
    id: "id1"
} ... {
    id: "idn"
}]
```

Doing that will get you objects which have id, but they don't have the class methods because you haven't instantiated the class, you'll need to do something like:

```
this.someArray = json.results.map(item => Object.assign(new someClass(), item));
```

Comment: This is the correct reason (although that implementation did not work for me). The object was of type object, but not of the type of my class. I initialize it as an object of that type, populate the fields, and now my function works great! thanks very much Nitzan.